# Building an encapsulated but extensible animation library in c++

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern, dynamic-dispatch

I am building an animation library in c++.  The library will include a system for modeling and rendering scenes.  The requirements of the system are

1. *Separation of modeling and rendering*.  Information about the state of the scene should be stored separately from procedures from rendering the scene.
2. *Extensible modeling and rendering*.  If the library itself defines a `node` class, a user of the library should be able to define a new type `custom_node` that extends the functionality of `node` (probably through inheritance, but maybe through some other means).  The user should then be able specify a custom procedure for rendering a `custom_node`.  In doing so, the user should somehow be able to take advantage of rendering procedures already present in the library.  The user should also be able to define new procedures for rendering library nodes. **Addition**: the user should be able to define whole rendering systems and select which one to use to render a scene.  Suppose, for instance, that the library includes a photorealistic rendering system, but a user wants to render scenes with a barebones schematic rendering system.  The user should be able to implement such a renderer using a common rendering interface that the animation library uses under the hood during the animation loop (render frame, update scene, render next frame, etc).
3. *Encapsulation of the library.* To extend the functionality of the library to custom `node`s and rendering procedures, a user shouldn't need to edit the underlying code of the library.

A failed approach: use a tree of `node`s as the model of a scene.  Subclass `node` to make new node types.  Since the types of the children of a node may not be known until runtime, a node’s children are stored in a `vector<std::shared_ptr<node>>`.
Also define a top level `renderer` class, and subclass `renderer` to provide specific kinds of rendering.

```
class image;

class node {
    virtual image render(renderer &r) {return r.render(*this);}
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>> children;
    std::weak_ptr<node> parent;
    // ...
}

class renderer {
    image render(node &n) {/*rendering code */}
// ...
}
```

To render a scene, define a renderer

```
renderer r{};
```

and traverse the tree of nodes with your favorite traversal method.  As you encounter each `std::shared_ptr<node>` `n`, call

```
n->render(r);
```

This approach separates modeling and rendering, and it allows for extensibility.  To create a `custom_node`, a user of the library simply subclasses `node`

```
class custom_node : public node {
    virtual image render(renderer &r) override {return r.render(*this)}
}
```

This approach works fine until we try to provide a custom means of rendering our `custom_node`.  To do so, we try subclassing `renderer` and overloading the `render` method:

```
class custom_renderer : public renderer {
    image render(custom_node &n) {/*custom rendering code*/}
}
```

By itself, this doesn’t work.  Consider:

```
renderer &r = custom_renderer{};
std::shared_ptr<node> n = std::make_shared<custom_node>{};
n->render(r); // calls renderer::render(node &)
```

In order to call custom_renderer::render(custom_node &n), as desired, we need to add a virtual overload to our original renderer class:

```
class renderer {
    image render(node &n) {/*rendering code */}
    virtual image render(custom_node &n) = 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this destroys the encapsulation of the library because we have edited one of the library classes.

How, then, can we design a system that satisfies all 3 requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution, a variant on the type-erasure method proposed by Yakk.  More details on the problem and this specific approach can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ivme/94efaf217e12c93369d05b30da5db558).

```
struct image{};

struct renderable_concept {
  virtual image render() const = 0;
};

template <class WRAPPED, class RENDERER>
struct renderable_model : public renderable_concept {
  WRAPPED *w;
  RENDERER r;
  virtual image render() const final override {
    return r.render(*w);
  }
  renderable_model(WRAPPED *w_, RENDERER r_) : w(w_), r(r_) {}
};

struct node {
  template <class WRAPPED, class RENDERER>
  node(WRAPPED *w_, RENDERER r_) :
    p_renderable(new renderable_model<WRAPPED,RENDERER>(w_,r_)) {}

  template <class RENDERER>
  node(RENDERER r_) : node(this,r_) {}

  image render() {return p_renderable->render();}
  vector<shared_ptr<node>> children;
  unique_ptr<renderable_concept> p_renderable;
};

struct text_node : public node {
  template<class RENDERER>
  text_node(RENDERER r) : node(this,r) {}

  string val;
};

struct shape_node : public node {
  template<class RENDERER>
  shape_node(RENDERER r) : node(this,r) {}
};

struct color_renderer {
  image render(node &) const {/*implementation*/};
  image render(text_node &) const {/*implementation*/};
  image render(shape_node &) const {/*implementation*/};
};

struct grayscale_renderer {
  image render(node &) const {/*implementation*/};
  image render(text_node &) const {/*implementation*/};
  image render(shape_node &) const {/*implementation*/};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Type erasure.  The library provides render(some_data) functions.

We start with a few kinds of nodes.  Primitives are nodes that render(primitive) just draws something.

List nodes have children, and render(list_node) draws its contents.

The generic_node stores anything which has a render(?) overload.  It type erases the render(?) operation.  Calling render(generic_node) invokes that type-erased operation on the contained data.

list_node contains a vector of generic_nodes.

In order to add a new rendering type, you simply define a new type, overload render(new_type), then store it in a generic_node.

Here is a primitive implementation:

```
struct render_target {
  // stuff about the thing we are rendering on
};
struct renderable_concept {
  virtual ~renderable_concept() {}
  virtual void render_on( render_target* ) const = 0;
};
template<class T>
void render( render_target*, T const& ) = delete; // by default, nothing renders

struct emplace_tag {};
template<class T>
struct renderable_model : renderable_concept {
  T t;
  template<class...Us>
  renderable_model( emplace_tag, Us&&...us ):
    t{std::forward<Us>(us)...}
  {}
  void render_on( render_target* target ) const final override {
    render( target, t );
  }
};
template<class T>
struct emplace_as {};
struct generic_node {
  friend void render( render_target* target, generic_node const& node ) {
    if (!node.pImpl) return;
    node.pImpl->render_on(target);
  }
  template<class T, class...Us>
  generic_node( emplace_as<T>, Us&&... us):
    pImpl( std::make_shared<renderable_model<T>>(emplace_tag{}, std::forward<Us>(us)...) )
  {}
  generic_node() = default;
  generic_node(generic_node&&)=default;
  generic_node(generic_node const&)=default;
  generic_node& operator=(generic_node&&)=default;
  generic_node& operator=(generic_node const&)=default;
private:
  std::shared_ptr<renderable_concept> pImpl;
};
```

Now, how to make a list node.

```
struct list_node {
  std::vector<generic_node> nodes;
  friend void render( render_target* target, list_node const& self ) {
    for (auto&& node:self.nodes)
      render(target, node);
  }
  list_node(std::vector<generic_node> ns):nodes(std::move(ns)) {}
  list_node() = default;
  list_node(list_node&&)=default;
  list_node& operator=(list_node&&)=default;
};

template<class T, class...Args>
generic_node make_node( Args&&... args ) {
  return {emplace_as<T>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
template<class T>
generic_node make_node( T&& t ) {
  return {emplace_as<std::decay_t<T>>{}, std::forward<T>(t) };
}
```

How about a node that prints hello world when rendered?

```
struct printing_node {
  std::string message;
  friend void render( render_target* target, printing_node const& self ) {
    std::cout << self.message;
  }
};
```

Test code:

```
auto list = make_node( list_node{{
  make_node( printing_node{{"hello"}} ),
  make_node( printing_node{{"world"}} )
}});
render_target target;
render(&target, list);
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da259a5ce07ff030).

Generic nodes are immutable shared pointer based value types that do little work when copied.

Comment: How to handle custom rendering with this approach?  Suppose we have a standard rendering system and a bold rendering system.  We want something like:
render(standard,printing_node{{"hello"}}); // prints "hello"
render(bold,printing_node{{"hello"}}); // prints "HELLO" 
Where would the custom capitalization code go?